# Web application to measure distances using camera

Tags: web-apps, augmented-reality

There are several Augmented Reality/Virtual Reality solutions that run on a web browser and are mobile friendly, so people don't need to download an app.

For example, this JavaScript library AR.js has an example where it detects two tangible stickers on the objects, and calculates the distance between using them as a reference. Here is a link to it:

[AR.js Measure-It](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/measure-it.html)

What I would like to ask is, is there any web application that can measure the distances without using stickers or reference objects, similar to built-in iOS application "Measure" where you basically point and drag.

I believe it is doable, since there are web applications that places some appliances on your kitchen counter, which also calibrates itself by moving the camera like "Measure" app does.

Comment: Welcome Mehmet!  Where/how did you find the example you provided?

Comment: If you mean AR.js, I searched github and come up their repositeries. They have several examples [there](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/tree/master/three.js/examples). For the appliance thing, I can't find the link, but If I remember correctly they used a boilerplate AR core and predefined 3d models.